# Does Apple Company allow for apps to stream video from youtube?

Tags: swift, url, streaming

I need to write app(on swift) that streams video using url! So, My question is , can I write player that take url from youtube? Does Apple allow this ? Searching on internet I found only  Media Framework . However this frame work only uses url that directly points to the video (like http://someserver/moview.mpg4)
On youtube , there is no direct link to the videos.
So can someone help me to answer:

1. Does apple allow youtube streaming?
2. if yes, what framework to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can 'embed' YouTuve video playback in your app - YouTube provide an API and details here:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

You will see it uses a UIWebView which is a common technique to bridge web and native app technologies.